# How to autosend canned response to myself?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-canned-response

My financial institutions are constantly sending me emails about when my statements are available and when my bills are due. For many of these institutions, I have automatic payments set up, but it's hard for me to remember which is which, so I find myself putting in significant effort to find out.

Instead, I'd like to use Gmail's filters and canned responses to auto-email myself a statement about what mechanisms I have set up for each bank. If I can reply to each bank's emails to myself, that information will be right where I need it, when I need it.

I tried creating a filter for bank's messages and sending a canned response, but I'm unsure it's doing anything.

```
Matches: visa
Do this: Apply label "money", Send canned response "Visa card automatic payments"
```

Even after getting in new messages that match the search term, there are no canned responses in their threads, and no messages to the bank in `label:sent`. How can I get this relevant information in my banking threads?

Comment: Doesn't "send canned response" send an email to the sender, which is probably a "do not reply" address at the bank?

Comment: I think you're exactly correct. Any ideas on how to accomplish sending a note-to-self in light of that?

Comment: Not really. You could forward the email to yourself (and maybe the tag will tip you off) or to a service like ifttt.com which can then do more with it.